# Ошибка с использованием контейнера и шаблона

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, vector, итераторы

столкнулся с ошибками в следующем коде

```
template<class ICustomStatistics>
class СStatistics_Periodic : public IBaseStatistics
{
protected:

    using statistics_block_pr = std::pair<double, ICustomStatistics>;
    using statistics_blocks_t = std::vector<statistics_block_pr>;
    using statistics_links_t  = std::vector<statistics_blocks_t::iterator>; // ОШИБКА
```

> Error C2923   'std::vector':
>   'std::vector,std::allocator<_Ty>>::iterator'
>   is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Ty'

и

> Error C3203   'allocator': unspecialized class template can't be used as
>   a template argument for template parameter '_Alloc', expected a real
>   type

все на строчку

```
using statistics_links_t  = std::vector<statistics_blocks_t::iterator>;
```

Не могу понять - а что не нравится то?

Вектор объектов и вектор итераторов

Comment: Еще одна причина, почему Clang мне нравится больше. `error: template argument for template type parameter must be a type; did you forget 'typename'?`

Comment: Не уверен,  что прав,  но мне кажется,  в библиотеке должен быть шаблон итератора.  И если Вы собираетесь для вектора использовать итервтор,  то нужно не только класс вектора специализировать каким-то типом,  но и класс итератора тоже.  Сорри,  если не прав

Comment: Юрий Козлов , вы не правы. Каждый стандартный контейнер имеет свой итератор, и он уже является  специализированным именем

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan,  спасибо буду знать :)) ввиду особенностей сферы деятельности практически не доводилось сталкиваться с шаблонами, так что...  знания давние,  теоретические и подзабытые :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

При использовании зависимых (от параметра шаблона) имен необходимо использовать ключевое слово `typename`. Иначе, за неимением возможности определить, чем является `iterator`, компилятор по-умолчанию будет впоспринимать его как имя переменной.

```
using statistics_links_t  = std::vector<typename statistics_blocks_t::iterator>;
```

Comment: огромное спасибо
век живи - век учись